# Multiple Transformations in a Merged Video iOS

Tags: ios, video, merge, avassetwriter, avassetexportsession

Been working on with two different libraries: https://github.com/dev-labs-bg/swift-video-generator and https://github.com/Awalz/SwiftyCam.

These libraries provide the ability to record and instantly merge two different videos. When using the front facing (selfie) camera, I prefer the video to be mirrored (Snapchat style). It looks more normal. If I take two selfie videos and merge them, the video generator understands the `preferredTransform`, and using AVAssetWriter, correctly merges the videos together while keeping their mirrored appearance. Similarly, if there are two videos taken with the back camera, the generator understands the transform and merges the videos together.

However, if there is a selfie video taken (mirrored by Swifty Cam), and then it is merged with a video with the back camera, the generator doesn't understand how to make multiple transformations, and the merged video takes on the `preferredTransform` of the first video taken and flips one of the videos that shouldn't be flipped.

How do you deal with multiple transformations when merging video on iOS?

Comment: did you find the solution ? Please share if found

Answer (score 0):

I would apply a *CIFilter* to the captured frames. It's fast (processing wise), fairly simple and there are tons of examples if you google.

Start off with having a look at Apples -> [CIFunHouse](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CIFunHouse/Listings/CIFunHouse_FHViewController_m.html)

Then when you're up to speed, this kernel filter reverses the image.

```
kernel vec4 coreImageKernel(sampler image)
{
    vec2 pixCoord=samplerCoord(image);
    pixCoord.x=samplerSize(image).x-pixCoord.x;
    return sample(image, pixCoord);
}
```

Or use the built in filter *CIAffineTransform* -> [CIAffineTransform](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html) if you don't want to write your own stuff.

/Anders.

Comment: @andres CIAffineTransform is not working for me